# How to convert string to a function name?

Tags: matlab

How would I go about converting x = 'abs' Into abs so that I could do z =    abs(-5) = 5. Or where x = 'randfunc' where 'randfunc' can be any input string relating to a function.

```
>> x

x =

abs

>> x(-5)
Subscript indices must either be real positive
integers or logicals.
```

Comment: You'e not trying to convert it to an integer, you're trying to evaluate it as a function name.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm after (It's late and I'm tired :( ) How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`str2func`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html):

```
x = 'abs';
fh = str2func(x);
fh(-5)               % Prints 5
```